# Combine rich:orderingList with rich:inplaceInput

Tags: richfaces

I would like to have a list of entries which I can shift/order and at the same time editable. So I tought to combine rich:orderingList with rich:inplaceInput this way:

```
<rich:orderingList value="#{detailModel.afterObject.metadata.getTitlesAsList()}"
                            var="title" itemLabel="#{title.value}" itemValue="#{title.position}" listWidth="300px">
    <rich:panel style="width:300px;">
        <rich:inplaceInput value="#{title.value}"/>
    </rich:panel>
</rich:orderingList>
```

I get the list which I can order, but the entries are not editable.

Do I miss something or it is not possible doing so?

Maybe combining other components?